# Regular Expression to restrict special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

i have an address field in my form and i want to restrict 
`* | \ " : < > [ ] { }  \ ( ) '' ; @ & $` 
i have tried with

```
var nospecial=/^[^* | \ " : < > [ ] { } ` \ ( ) '' ; @ & $]+$/;
            if(address.match(nospecial)){
                alert('Special characters like * | \ " : < > [ ] { } ` \ ( ) \'\' ; @ & $ are not allowed');
                return false;
```

but it is not working. Please tell me what i missed?

Comment: Escaping of `]` in your character class

Comment: @Juhana - Wrong. Note the `^` as the first character of the class; that negates the sense of the match. It will match if the entire address has only characters that match _none_ of the (remaining) characters in the class.

Comment: @TedHopp oops, you're right! Although then the if clause is wrong, it gives the error message if the regex matches...

Comment: @Juhana - You're right about the `if`! I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to escape the closing bracket (as well as the backslash) inside your character class. You also don't need all the spaces:

```
var nospecial=/^[^*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]+$/;
```

I got rid of all your spaces; if you want to restrict the space character as well, add one space back in.

**EDIT** As @fab points out in a comment, it would be more efficient to reverse the sense of the regex:

```
var specials=/[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]/;
```

and test for the presence of a special character (rather than the absence of one):

```
if (specials.test(address)) { /* bad address */ }
```

Comment: In addition, a better solution would be to *test* against a single bad character: `if (/[*|and-so-on]/.test(address)) alert('not allowed!');`

Comment: @fab - Why better? I don't imagine that there's any performance benefit one way or the other. In either case, matching will look at every character, testing against the class, until a match is found or the end of the string. Also, your suggestion requires a separate test to rule out an empty address string.

Comment: @fab - Well, I take it back. Evidently your approach is faster (at least in the Chrome browser), at least according to [this test](http://jsperf.com/character-class/) (even with the extra test against an empty string). I can't say why that would be (unless the JS engine multi-threads the match on my multi-core pc, which is entirely possible).

Comment: To explain the performance difference: With your expression, a match is not found before the end of the string because it ends with `$`. Technically it has to track back the whole string *and* test every character, while my expression checks character by character without backtracking and quits at the first special character because `test()` only *checks* if the expression matches, while `match()` *finds* all the matches.

Comment: @fab - The backtracking makes sense, and that probably explains the difference. However, it doesn't need to get to the end of the string to fail; once it finds a character that can't match, there's reason to backtrack, but no reason to go on.

Comment: You're right, I confused matching and failing. both expressions *end* as soon as one special character is found and *move on* until the end if no special character is in the string.

Answer (score 3):

/[$&+,:;=?[]@#|{}'<>.^*()%!-/]/

below one shouldn't allow to enter these character and it will return blank space

```
.replace(/[$&+,:;=?[\]@#|{}'<>.^*()%!-/]/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function

```
function checkSpcialChar(event){
    if(!((event.keyCode >= 65) && (event.keyCode <= 90) || (event.keyCode >= 97) && (event.keyCode <= 122) || (event.keyCode >= 48) && (event.keyCode <= 57))){
        event.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    event.returnValue = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this this will fix the issue

String patttern = r"[!-/:-@[-`{-~]";

RegExp regExp = RegExp(patttern);