# regex in javascript that restrict some special characters like "%,+,>,<,`"

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to check the not condition. I just want the regex to check for the given characters and return `false` if any.

```
 <form name="f" onsubmit="return onlyAlphabets()">
     <input type="text" name="nm" onkeypress="return myFunction(event)">
     <div id="notification"></div>
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
  function myFunction(e) {
  var regex = /^[%+<>]/g;
  if (!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
     return true;
  } 
  else {
```

```html
<form name="f" onsubmit="return onlyAlphabets()">
      <input type="text" name="nm" onkeypress="return myFunction(event)">
      <div id="notification"></div>
      <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
      function myFunction(e) {
      var regex = /^[%+<>]/g   //   /^\d+$/; // /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
      if (!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
         return true;
      } 
      else {         
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: <form name="f" onsubmit="return onlyAlphabets()">
      <input type="text" name="nm" onkeypress="return myFunction(event)">
      <div id="notification"></div>
      <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <script>
      function myFunction(e) {
      var regex = /[^%+<>]/g;
      if (!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
         return true;
      } 
      else {         
        return false;
      }
    }
</script>

Comment: var specials=/[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]/;
if (specials.test(address)) { /* bad address */ }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745961/regular-expression-to-restrict-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="f" onsubmit="return onlyAlphabets()">
  <input type="text" name="nm" onkeypress="return myFunction(event)">
  <div id="notification"></div>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
  function myFunction(e) {
  var regex = /[^%+<>]/g;
  if (!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
     return true;
  } 
  else {         
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question ? Why post a question ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : True.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not provided a full list of what you want disabled so this is more general purpose

```
myFunction = e => /[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@%!&$]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))
```

---